# TAB highlights next word instead of indenting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, highlight

When formatting code in Visual Studio 2019 I cannot indent the code with TAB key to line up parts of my code. I know in VS Code there is "Toggle Use of Tab Key for Setting Focus" - however, I could not find this in Keyboard options. Instead it highlights next segment of the code, e.g. variable name.

How do I get TAB to indent my code normally again?

Screenshot showing the highlighting. Happens every time after pressing tab after accessor keyword:

[image: Screenshot showing the highlighting. Happens every time after pressing tab after accessor keyword.]

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: Do you have to use TAB to indent your code normally?  Based on my search, you can try to press CtrlK, CtrlF shortcut applies the indenting and space formatting.

Comment: @Paramecium13 Yes I do. I couldn't find the options there. Do you know what's the source of the issue?